# What is the Significance of Magetic Field Energy Density?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If we consider electrostatic field energy density for an electrical field then by analysis we find that it is the representation of the total electrostatic potential energy of the considered system.That is if we integrate (Electric Field Energy Density)*(Infinitesimal Small Volume) over entire space we get the total electrostatic potential energy of the considered system.But in case of magnetic fields how can we associate any magnetic field potential energy as it does not perform any work on an isolated charge particle.I am considering all the magnetic fields and particles under its influence are isolated charge paricles.So don't consider any rotational work done performed by a magnetic field on a magnetic dipole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Magnetic force" does not need to do work for the "magnetic energy" to change. There is no work-energy relation between these two concepts only. The magnetic field is said to store magnetic energy because to create it, work has to be done by external bodies (against induced electrical forces originating in the system), and this work can be recovered if the field is decreased (by suitable operation), as work of the electric forces induced in the system acting on the external bodies.